# Need to select all rows (occupied and blank rows) in a range of columns to format later

Tags: excel, vba, union

I have tried to do this several different ways, I think using a union of ranges or a for loop would be best. Right now I can't get this union to work and I can't figure out why.

I have several columns (D:G) I am formatting and the number of rows change every time so this needs to be dynamic.

I want to be able to select all the rows in D:G, including the in-between blank rows, until the last occupied row.

[image]

I am starting simple by just trying to select the union of ranges.
This is my code:

```
Dim DGunion As Range
Set DGunion = Union((Range("D2", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))), _
(Range("E2", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))), _
(Range("F2", Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))), _
(Range("G2", Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))))
DGunion.Select
```

The error I get is run time error 424 object required

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: You don't need union here you can get the entire range with ```Range("D2:G" & lastrow)``` where ```lastrow = Cells(rows.count, 4).End(xlUp).row```

Comment: Warcupine, Wow that worked perfectly. I had tried to do something like that previously but couldn't figure out how to make the last row variable work for a range of columns. Thank you!

Comment: Scot Craner, the error was run time 424 object required

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside that you don't need `Union` for this task, reason your code fails is that you have too many brackets.

You've got brackets around each parameter you're passing to `Union`.  This over rides the default `ByRef` behavior with `ByVal`, therefore passing the Value array, which `Union` can't handle.